# Use $gt operator to return document values among all the objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is one of many similar objects in shopping list collection. How do I do a query to get the list of only the "name" of people buying more than 2 "Noodles"?
Please help me figure this out, thanks in advance.

I assume this should have the $gt operator but I am not sure how to execute it correctly.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591422529f75f9119575c1d8"),
    "name" : "Hisham",
    "age" : 20,
    "address" : {
        "house" : "HomeName",
        "street" : "Fairyland",
        "city" : "Faketon",
        "pincode" : 000000
    },
    "itemlist" : [
        {
            "iname" : "Soap",
            "quantity" : 2,
            "price" : 10,
            "rate" : 20,
            "itemID" : "1"
        },
        {
            "iname" : "Mirror",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "price" : 600,
            "rate" : 600,
            "itemID" : "4"
        },
        {
            "iname" : "Noodles",
            "quantity" : 4,
            "price" : 50,
            "rate" : 200,
            "itemID" : "5"
        },
        {
            "iname" : "Plug",
            "quantity" : 2,
            "price" : 50,
            "rate" : 100,
            "itemID" : "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the aggregation framework like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
   {  
      $unwind:"$itemlist"
   },
   {  
      $match:{  
         "itemlist.iname":"Noodles"
      }
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$itemlist.iname",
         name:{  
            $first:"$name"
         },
         count:{  
            $sum:1
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $match:{  
         count:{  
            $gte:2
         }
      }
   }
])
```

How it works:

1. unwind the itemlist array with **`$unwind`**
2. keep only `Noodles` item
3. count occurence of `Noodles` using **`$group`**
4. keep only document where `count` >= 2

Answer (score 0):

You can select the all documents that match your criteria using the `$elemMatch` operator in the `$match`. From there all you need is a `$group` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "itemlist": { 
            "$elemMatch": { 
                "quantity": { "$gt": 2 }, 
                "iname": "Noodles"
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "names": { "$push": "$name" } } }
])
```